# Returning scope data in a collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Below is a function I have on a model which brings back a `Service` with the data from three relationships. The scope `closeTo` contains data relating to how far a location is from a service which I would also like returned, but it currently only uses it to figure out distances.

```
return Service::with(['relationship1', 'relationship2', 'locations'])
  ->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($latitude, $longitude, $radius){
    $query->closeTo($latitude, $longitude, $radius);
  })
->get();
```

the `$query->closeTo` uses the function below, and I want to send the distance data back with the `return` from the first function.

```
public function scopeCloseTo($query, $latitude, $longitude, $radius = 25)
    {
      $haversine = "(3959 * acos(cos(radians($latitude))
                     * cos(radians(latitude))
                     * cos(radians(longitude)
                     - radians($longitude))
                     + sin(radians($latitude))
                     * sin(radians(latitude))))";
     return $query
        ->select(['id', 'ccg', 'ccg_code']) //pick the columns you want here.
        ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
        ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$radius]);
    }
```

Whats the best wat to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the closeTo statement to your eager loading as a Closure instead of a string:

```
return Service::with(['relationship1', 'relationship2',
       'locations' => function ($query) use ($latitude, $longitude, $radius){
    $query->closeTo($latitude, $longitude, $radius);
}])->whereHas('locations', function ($query) use ($latitude, $longitude, $radius){
    $query->closeTo($latitude, $longitude, $radius);
  })
->get();
```

Comment: I have used this elsewhere, didn't cross my mind to use it here like this